# ffmpeg - extract subtitles from piped input?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have found two separate commands that I want to combine. One for taking piped input:

`ffmpeg -i pipe:0`

And another for extracting subtitles from a `.ts` file:

`ffmpeg -i "movie=file.ts[out0+subcc]" -map s output.srt`

But I can't work out how to combine them.

`ffmpeg -i "movie=pipe:0[out0+subcc]" -map s output.srt`

doesn't work. I'm kind of an ffmpeg newbie, so any ideas?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -lavfi "[0]copy[out0+subcc]" -map s output.srt` - it's a piped input so don't know how subtitle extraction will behave.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, but I'm seeing different input descriptions - when piping it's `mpegts` with `Program 174` and 5 streams (video is #0:1), with a file it's `lavfi` and only two streams - video is #0:0. Any ideas?

Comment: Then try `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 20M -i pipe:0 -lavfi "[0:1]copy[out0+subcc]" -map s output.srt`

Answer (score 1):

The solution requires escaping the colon after the "pipe".

Depending on your shell, and quoting rules, you'll need from 2 backslashes to... well, who knows :-)

Here's what has worked for me:

`cat input.ts | ffmpeg -f lavfi -i 'movie=pipe\\:0[out+subcc]' -map s output.srt`

If you use double quotes you'll need at least another backslash:

`cat input.ts | ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "movie=pipe\\\:0[out+subcc]" -map s output.srt`

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5229